# Two nics with different subnets

Tags: networking

I have a Dell Server with 2 nic call em1 and em2 running Ubuntu Server 14.04,
em1 is connected to my home network/router with a IP address 192.168.1.4
and em2 is connected to some multimedia equipment that broadcasts satellite feeds over UDP Multicast, em2 IP address is 10.0.0.1 and the equipment connected to em2 have a IP address 10.0.0.10-15.

How can I access the Multicast Address 224.10.10.1:6000 em2 from my home network 192.168.1.x ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Also you can add route to specific address on you pc connected on home lan

```
route add -host 224.10.10.1 gw ip_address_of_home_network_router
```

Comment: hi i did some changes eth1mto em2 and eth0 to em1, but that did not work. i cant reach the router on ip address 192.168.1.1 from em2 (10.0.0.1) and cant not ping the multimedia devices on 10.0.0.10-15 from em1 (192.168.1.4)

Comment: You must add route. On pc 192.168.1.xxx add route to network 10.0.0.xx. `route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1`. Also you need to add route to multi media mashines `route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.1`

Comment: okay, but i need to access the multicast address that are connected to em2 within the server because im trying to do transcoding. so on the server with the 2 nic em1 and em2 i just add route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1 and route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.1 and that should work or?

Comment: `# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
        address   192.168.1.4
        netmask   255.255.255.0
        network   192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway   192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto em2
iface em2 inet static
        address   10.0.0.1
        netmask   255.255.255.0
        network   10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
        gateway  192.168.1.4 `